# Rails app. Dependency installed with yarn. How to get to the files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

I have a Rails app. I installed fullPage.js library with yarn. The library is in node_modules.

How can I load the files in my app? I am trying:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullpage.css" />
```

This is not working. I get:

> GET http://localhost:3000/fullpage.css 404 (Not Found)

I've tried to import this file in application.scss, in application.js.

I've tried to put the whole path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/fullpage.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/fullpage.css" />
```

But I can not manage to load the file. Could someone help me understand, how to load files from the folder node_modules in a Rails app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in application.css:

`*= require fullpage.js/dist/fullpage`

Rails already looks inside `node_modules` directory when loading assets, so you should omit that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I get an error, that rails tried to find the file in following paths: app/assets/config, /app/assets/images, /app/assets/javascripts, /app/assets/stylesheets. I don't get why he doesn't look in node_modules

Comment: Does your `config/initializers/assets.rb` contain `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')`?

Comment: yes: # Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')